# PHP tooltip that queries database table

Tags: php, mysql, tooltip

I have a grid that displays data from a table called DETAILS. One of the columns in this grid is called SERVICE, and it displays all the services from the DETAILS table. As you can see, there is also a column for ID.

```
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>{$Row[ID]}</td>";
 echo "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">{$Row[SERVICE]}</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
```

What I need to do now have the content of the cell display a tooltip when the user hovers over it.

The hover will take the ID and query SERVICE_TABLE. The tooltip will return the data for the ID and display the contents from SERVICE_TABLE.

I hope I am wording this correctly.

I'm not sure exactly where to start.  I'm not sure where the query should even go.

Please help.

Comment: AJAX would be a start.

Comment: You can query SERVICE_TABLE before to create the html table, like that you'll be able to put the information you want in a title tag directly.  
Otherwise you'll need Ajax to query each time you want to complete a title tag, but I'm not sure of a JavaScript event that will allow you to do that.